# When to properly flush buffer when working with OpenSSL calls like `SSL_connect()` when BIO is not backed by a socket?

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm a bit confused by expected proper usage pattern of APIs such as `SSL_connect()`, `SSL_write()`, etc.  I've read up on some other posts on SO and elsewhere, and those that I found are all centered around blocking or non-blocking sockets (i.e. where BIO is given a socket to use for underlying IO), and the return errors `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` and `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` from calls in such configurations are pretty clear how to handle.

However, I'm a bit puzzled as to what the proper handling would be when *BIO is set up without underlying IO socket*, and instead all IO is handled via memory buffers. (The reason for such a setup is because encrypted data stream is not immediately sent over a vanila socket, but rather may be enveloped over other protocols or delivery mechanisms, and cannot be written to some socket directly).  E.g. the BIO is set up as

```
auto readBio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
auto writeBio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
auto ssl = SSL_new(...);
SSL_set_bio(ssl, readBio, writeBio);
```

My assumption - albeit it appears to be incorrect - that after making a call to say `SSL_connect()`, it would tell me when it's time to pick up its output from write buffer using `BIO_read()` call and deliver that buffer (by whatever custom underlying transport means) to the other end peer; and likewise when to feed it data from peer.  In other words, something akin to:

```
while (true) {
    auto ret = SSL_connect(ssl);  // or SSL_read(), SSL_write(), SSL_shutdown() in other contexts...
    if (ret <= 0) {
        auto err = SSL_get_error(ssl, ret);
        switch(err) {
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
                auto buf = magicallyReadDataFromPeer();
                BIO_write(buf, ...);
                continue;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
                Buffer buf;
                BIO_read(buf, ...);
                magicallySendDataToPeer();
                continue;
        }
    } else break;
}
```

But I'm noticing that the first call to `SSL_connect()` always results in `SSL_EROR_WANT_READ` with nothing sent to peer to actually initiate TLS handshake, and so it blocks indefinitely.

If after calling `SSL_connect()` I do flush the buffer by doing `BIO_read()` and sending it out, then things seem to proceed.  Same seems for `SSL_write()` calls, but then it seems that if I always flush buffer after call, and then check for `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`, I'd be flushing the buffer twice (with second one probably being a no-op) and that seems nonsensical. It also seems strange that I should just always ignore `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` of every SSL_connect/accept/write/read/shutdown calls since I'd be flushing always after each call.

And so I'm puzzled about what's the proper and expected dance between SSL_connect/etc and BIO_read/write calls and their tying relationship of `SSL_ERROR_WANT_*` values, *specifically* when using mem buffer instead of socket or file descriptor for underlying IO.

Comment: Have you considered attaching a debugger and stepping through the SSL_connect call? That will point you to where exactly it is trying to read.

Comment: @Botje, I use SSL in C# (on macOS) and in C++, but both apps are high-volume, real-time systems that are not conducive to attaching debugger as thing will simply start timing out.  I'm also using a pre-built SSL lib and don't have build for it to generate debug symbols. IOW, it's possible to start debugging inside SSL_connect, but would take a lot of prep, as well as figuring out OpenSSL code itself! And I'm not sure if it'll answer how it expects to handle buffer management anyway.  It's a doc issue that is missing the info  or knowledge thing that I hope someone could impart.

Comment: General searches for "TLS handshake" and [this part of a test](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/33388b44b67145af2181b1e9528c381c8ea0d1b6/test/servername_test.c#L90-L136) seems to validate your assumption that SSL_connect should send a client hello and wait for the corresponding server hello. Do you have pending errors somewhere? Can you expand your snippet to a [mcve] so other people can dig into it?

Comment: Check out https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/BIO_new_bio_pair.html "As the data is buffered, SSL_operation() may return with an ERROR_SSL_WANT_READ condition, but there is still data in the write buffer. An application must not rely on the error value of SSL_operation() but must assure that the write buffer is always flushed first. Otherwise a deadlock may occur as the peer might be waiting for the data before being able to continue."

Comment: @Grober, thanks, that warning section provides a bit of insight, and somewhat matches my observation, in that current code works only because we already do forceful flushes after every ssl operation call.  But then, does it imply that `case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` should just be a no-op since we just flushed the buffer already?  I.e. that what I'm referring to in: _"It also seems strange that I should just always ignore SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE of every SSL_connect/accept/write/read/shutdown calls since I'd be flushing always after each call."_?

Comment: Is SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE ever returned? As per documentation "Writes to memory BIOs will always succeed if memory is available: that is their size can grow indefinitely.". As far as i know SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE is only returned when the write buffer is full. But an ever growing buffer can't be full.

Comment: @Grober, that's a good question.  It doesn't seem to be returned in connect's case - idk if read/write return it ever.  The test seems a bit probabilistic (as in it might happen _sometimes_).  One of the reasons I posted the question is that current code (which seems to work, but suspected of occasional stalls) on `SSL_write` flushes buffer if it sees status `WANT_WRITE` or status > 0.  But applying same exact handling to `SSL_connect` stalls connect call hard.  Hence there appears to be asymmetry in what seems should be the same. ...

Comment: ... So what I have is some arrangement that _seems_ to work most of the time, but is suspect of occasional stalls, and no clarity on what proper contract is. The seems-to-work'ish is where I already am...